# Por que cada browser interpreta/formata um HTML mal formatado diferentemente dos demais?

Tags: html, webforms, navegador-de-internet, formatação

Essa semana me deparei com um *bug* em um sistema. Esse sistema foi desenvolvido em Asp Web Forms e em determinada página tem um `input` que está como `hidden`.

Ao realizar um Post percebi que no Chrome e no Firefox o valor desse `input` não estava sendo enviado na *request* e no IE o mesmo era enviado.

Analisando o código, percebi algo de estranho nesse `input`, a *tag* do mesmo não estava sendo fechada, ficando então dessa forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<% response.Write(vID) %>"
```

Vejam que falta um `>`. Em cada navegador que testei, IE, Chrome e Firefox, o HTML gerado fica diferente dos demais.

Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Firefox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

IE:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque eles são diferentes :P Não sei se consigo responder melhor que isto :) De qualquer forma o que é mal formatado só é interpretado por liberalidade, se está errado, não confie naquilo.

Comment: Na verdade, são resultados equivalentes. O único detalhe é que o Chrome não segue à risca as recomendações W3C/WHATWG neste caso, que definem que os atributos booleanos devem conter ou uma *string* vazia ou uma *string* com o valor desejado. Estou comentando por estar sem tempo agora. Quem sabe após o almoço em converta em resposta, caso ninguém responda antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada navegador tem sua engine, que interpreta o HTML, Javascript, Css. O ruim disto (ou não) é que cada navegador vai / pode apresentar o seu site de uma forma distinta. Este erro que comentou ainda não é tão gritante como questões de alinhamento que as vezes nos fazem arrancar os cabelos. Principalmente no IE(O diferentão...)

Dá uma pesquisada nos engines dos navegadores, verá que há muitas diferenças entre eles e que isso é inclusive uma grande preocupação em sistemas que devem rodar com características cross-browser...